# twisted.protocols.ftp.FTPClient and Deferreds

Tags: python, ftp, twisted, deferred

Like most it's taking me a while to get used to using Deferreds but I'm slowly getting there. However, it's not clear to me how I can process a response and then call another FTP command *using the processed response* when using Twisted's FTP module. I'm using the the [example FTP code](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/ftpclient.py) as my jumping off point.

I want to connect to a FTP server, get all the top level directories, then enter each one and download all the files.

First I connect:

```
creator = ClientCreator(reactor, FTPClient, config.opts['username'], config.opts['password'], passive=config.opts['passive'])
creator.connectTCP(config.opts['host'], config.opts['port']).addCallback(connectionMade).addErrback(connectionFailed)
reactor.run()
```

It connects successfully, so my `connectionMade` function gets called:

```
def connectionMade(ftpClient):
    # Get a detailed listing of the current directory
    fileList = FTPFileListProtocol()
    d = ftpClient.list('.', fileList)
    d.addCallbacks(getSortedDirectories, fail, callbackArgs=(fileList,))
    d.addCallback(enterDirs)
```

As you see, I queue up `getSortedDirectories` and then `enterDirs`.

```
def getSortedDirectories(result, fileListProtocol):
    # Go through all directories from greatest to least
    dirs = [directory for directory in sorted(fileListProtocol.files, reverse=True) if directory['filetype'] == 'd']
    return dirs
```

My question is, how do I go through the directories in `enterDirs`?

```
def enterDirs(dirs):
    for directory in dirs:
        print "We'd be entering '%s' now." % directory
```

Should I be passing `ftpClient` to `enterDirs` like `fileList` is passed to `getSortedDirectories` and then make my download requests?

```
d.addCallback(enterDirs, callbackArgs=(ftpClient,))

def enterDirs(dirs, ftpClient):
    for directory in dirs:
        fileList = FTPFileListProtocol()
        d = ftpClient.list(directory, fileList)
        d.addCallbacks(downloadFiles, fail, callbackArgs=(directory, fileList, ftpClient))

def downloadFiles(result, directory, fileListProtocol, ftpClient):
    for f in fileListProtocol.files if f.filetype == '-':
        fileConsumer = FileConsumer()
        ftpClient.retrieveFile(os.path.join(directory['filename'], file['filename']), fileConsumer)
```

Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be passing ftpClient to
>   enterDirs like fileList is passed to
>   getSortedDirectories and then make my
>   download requests? ... Is this the
>   best approach?

I do think that passing the client object explicitly as an argument is indeed the best approach -- mostly, it's spare and elegant.  The main alternative would be to code a class and stash the client object into an instance variable, which seems a bit more cumbersome; to use a global variable for the purpose would, in my opinion, be the least desirable alternative (the fewer globals around, the better!-).

Comment: So that is the common pattern in the Twisted world? Ok, thanks.

Comment: @pr1001, it's not especially Twisted-specific: it's common to architectures based on callbacks (even outside Python, e.g, in Javascript!-).

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was hoping that Deferreds would give me some magic to program in a more procedural style (like how I have two callbacks on the Deferred in `connectionMade`) while still keeping the asynchronous nature of it all.

Comment: @pr1001, deferreds let you pass fixed extra args to be passed to each callback when it's called -- what else besides that do you need for "more procedural style"?  Maybe you can edit your Q to add some "dream-world code" that you'd like to be able to write (without black magic happening behind your back of course) to help us show you how to implement that...?